# How to transpose columns while storing in another table in msaccess

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a temporary table in MS Access with the following column headers

```
ProjectID, JanuaryCost, FebruaryCost ,...DecemberCost Year
1001        $25           $50             $35          2016
1001        $15           $22             $26          2017
```

I wish to store these records in another access table which has the following fields

```
ProjectID ,  IncurredDate , Cost
1001          01/2016        $25
1001          02/2016        $50
.
.
1001         12/2017         $26
```

How do i do this ?
I am not an extreme expert at access so would be great if someone could give me a sample query instead of just suggest an approach like (Normalize)

Comment: Well, this is not a free code writing service. Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: You are looking to generate months along the way here, and the logic isn't completely clear to me.  Your question would require a moderate amount of SQL olympics to achieve.

Comment: I am importing an excel file into access which is structured in the form of Table 1 above. I wish to take the Column name (lets say January) and Year combination to achieve this.

Comment: @GhostCat  this is a website to help coders which is why i asked for a "sample" query and not the actual code. Thanks for helping (not !)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UNION query to rearrange the source data into normalized structure.

`SELECT ProjectID, "1/1/" & [Year] AS IncurredDate, [JanuaryCost] AS Cost FROM tablename
UNION SELECT ProjectID, "2/1/" & [Year], [FebruaryCost] FROM tablename
...
UNION SELECT ProjectID, "12/1/" & [Year], [DecemberCost] FROM tablename;`

Must use SQLView of query builder and type or copy/paste lines. There is a limit of 50 SELECT lines.

IncurredDate field should be a date/time type and populate with full date as I show in example. Or if really want only month and year in a text field, populate as YYYY/MM to enable easier sorting/filtering or put year and month in separate fields.